# AngularJs::First Radio button should got selected of every radio button group after filter and set IsSelected to true and other to false

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

> **Please check the Example**

```js
//
var ngApp = angular.module('app', []);
 
ngApp.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

$scope.setSelected = function ($data, $pData) {
        angular.forEach($data, function (cu) {
                cu.IsSelected = false; 
        });
      $pData.IsSelected = true; 
    };
    $scope.BusArray = [
 [{

  "BusName": "Ax. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 1200,
  "IsSelected": true
 }, {

  "BusName": "Bx. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 1600,
  "IsSelected": false
 }, {

  "BusName": "Bx. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 800,
  "IsSelected": false
 }, {

  "BusName": "Nx. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 400,
  "IsSelected": false
 }],
 [{

  "BusName": "Ax. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 1100,
  "IsSelected": true
 }, {

  "BusName": "Nx. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 1400,
  "IsSelected": false
 }, {

  "BusName": "Nx. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 600,
  "IsSelected": false
 }, {

  "BusName": "Bx. Travels",
  "Origin": "DEL",
  "Destination": "JAI",
  "TotalFare": 500,
  "IsSelected": false
 }]
];
    
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" >
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    
Type(Bx/ Nx / Ax): <input type="text" ng-model="checkPrice">
        <div ng-repeat="buses in BusArray">
        <span>group{{$index+1}}</span>
        <form>
      <div ng-repeat="bus in dd=(buses|filter:checkPrice)">
    <label style="font-size:12px; background-color:green; padding:2px;">
                <input name="{{$parent}}" id="{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" type="radio" ng-checked="bus.IsSelected" ng-click="setSelected(buses,bus)" />
                {{bus|json}}
               </label>
         
            </div>
              </form>
            <div>
        </div>
        
        <hr/>
     
    </div>
       {{BusArray | json}}
</div>
```

::

> **My need is::**
>
> ## ------------- Case::
>
> **If I type "bx" in the input box::** 
>   **group 1::** First radio button got selected and "is selected" set to true and others to false and if I remove the filter than it should set
>   to the old data(i.e "Bus Array").
>   **group 2:same as group 1

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes here .. check the fiddle - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgw02rwk/)

```
$scope.isSetSelected = function(isSet , $data , $pData,isFirst){
      if(isSet) return true;
      else{
        var isAnyDataSelected = false;
        angular.forEach($data, function (cu) {
                if (cu.IsSelected )
                  isAnyDataSelected = true;
        });
        if(isAnyDataSelected)
            return false;
        else if(isFirst)
          return true;
      }
 }
```

Comment: hi disha.. you are correct about the selection of first radio btn ...but my need is that it should set the "IsSelected": true  and others  to false in the array. and when I remove the filter first radio button sholud get selected set "IsSelected": true and others to false.